# file_get_contents() -> SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, json, facebook, ssl, curl

I had this piece of code to get the likes of a particular Facebook page in production since years:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/<facebook site id>';
echo json_decode(file_get_contents($url))->{'likes'};
```

Now we upgraded to PHP 5.6 and it stopped working with the following error message:

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents.php]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in <some page> on line 182

Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents.php]: Failed to enable crypto in <some site> on line 182

Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/<facebook site id>) [function.file-get-contents.php]: failed to open stream: operation failed in <some page> on line 182
```

Is there a simple way to fix this?

I know there is a referenced answer but this answer disables SSL verification and I don't want to implement a possible security hole!

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to TRUE by default starting with cURL 7.10
You could set it to FALSE again, although it would be wiser to set the CA certificates (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php for more info).

Also, keep in mind that file_get_contents will return FALSE on timeout, so it may be a good idea to :
- Set a lower timeout than the default php timeout of 0 seconds
- Handle any returns of FALSE